# Why the IUPAC naming of this compound is 6-hydroxycyclohex-2-en-1-one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

Should it not be 2hydroxycylohex-5-en-1-one?

Functional groups are usually given more priority than double/triple bonds, except in cases of Nitro, halides, etc.

Shouldn't the priority order be Ketone>alcohol>double bond for assigning locants. Ketone gets the least, then asigning rest in clockwise fashion with-OH at 2 and double bond at -5.

After Ketone, alcohol should be given the priority, not double bond,

> eg  (CH3-CH=CH-CH(OH)-CH3) is pent-3-en-2-ol, not pent-2-en-3-ol.

Shouldn't the same logic apply to this compound too?

Comment: "Shouldn't the priority order be ketone>alcohol>double bond for assigning locants?" No.
"Shouldn't the same logic apply to this compound too?" Yes, and that's why 6-hydroxycyclohex-2-en-1-one and pent-3-en-2-ol are both correct.

Comment: *"Functional groups are usually given more priority than double/triple bonds"* - citation needed! You're probably talking about *suffixes*, not *functional groups* (hence your exclusion of nitro and halides which are not suffixes), but here 'hydroxy' is not a suffix.